# xampp apache server stops

Tags: php, xampp

I was using xampp on my windows7 (32 bit) laptop but I upgraded to windows 10 recently. and since then I have been facing this issue. I have even tried to reinstall xampp but the issue won't get resolved. please help !

Comment: Check if there any program which is using the port 80 like Skype? This could help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946150/apache-is-not-running-from-xampp-control-panel

Comment: Also check if maybe MS-IIS got installed and blocks that port. Has also been reported.

Comment: thanks a lot! although that problem is resolved now as my apache server working successfully after changing the port. but now I am facing another issue that is the localhost page wont open up in any of my browsers?

Comment: Here is a complete guideline to setup XAMPP for vhost, it is worth it you go thought it, I very sure it will solve your issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27754367/how-to-setting-up-virtual-hosts-for-xampp-on-windows-full-gudieline/27754990#27754990

Comment: thanks ! that helped as for now :)