# xampp! Not able to connect on browser

Tags: apache, xampp, localhost

I am getting in a serious problem: My XAMPP Control Panel looks like this[image: Showing connected]

But when i go to browser, http://localhost then it show me this[image: Browser]

I checked my netstat and it showing me this
[image: netstat]

I can't figure out what's the major problem ??? 
What i am missing?
I changed my ports on xampp like on this [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946150/apache-is-not-running-from-xampp-control-panel), but my problem still exits

Help
Thanks in advance

Comment: Looks like its listening on port **81** rather than the default **80**, so , `http://localhost:81` if that works (and 80 is available, reconfigure to use 80)

Comment: But i am using port 80 earlier, so i checked that 'link' and changed to port 81. But now as you said , i reconfigure to port 80 again in httpd.config

Comment: Yeah it WORKS!! great....But what is the major problem in that? Changing again to port 80 which was showing me an error.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment , so I'll try to explain you what's happening here.

By default the HTTP port is 80 , when you open http://localhost you are telling the browser to do a "dns lookup" and after it finds the ip for localhost , it will try to open the connection using the default HTTP port. In this case localhost is set by default to route to http://127.0.0.1:80 . If you start your HTTP server at port 81 , your browser won't be able to find the server as it is trying to open a :80 connection.

If you want to keep the 81 port you could either change the browser configuration or change the HOST file to re-route localhost to 127.0.0.1:81.

Lastly , if you can't run at port 80 and you want to , you need to check for other software running at the 80 port and stop it.