# Apache server isn't starting on Xampp portable

Tags: apache, web, xampp

It may seems as a repeated question but my problem is that I couldn't be able to start Apache server on XAMPP Portable, I'm am aware of the issues that some aplications can cause since they can use the ports where apache is supposed to work, so I decide to change the apache running ports on httpd.conf and httpd-ssl.conf files to Listen on 8080 and 8001 respectively, here are some screenshots of the changes,

[http-conf1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y72RI.png), [http-conf2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5pbA4.png), [httpssl-conf1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HckVR.png), [httpssl-conf2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RjR1x.png)

In adition to that I also chage the configuration of the "Service & Port Settings" under XAMPP Control Panel, as shown in the folowing image,

[xampp-ports](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ybKxk.png)

Although, I did all these changes I still can´t get the apache instance running, and keep getting the following error [xampp-error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UoRaq.png), it's important to notice that **I´m trying to start apache service in a company workstation and I don't have any admin rights**, but I read that ports above 1250 didn't need any admin rigths to run services on them, so I don´t know what to do at this point, any suggestion from you guys would be really appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are lot's of answer to this problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17946150/apache-is-not-running-from-xampp-control-panel-error-apache-shutdown-unexpect), in particular I think that [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17978400/1262357) is the answer you are looking for:

> **Have you executed "setup_xampp.bat" script?**
> It's inside XAMPP folder and it must be executed every time you change XAMPP folder.

(Bolds are mine)

While not explicitly stated in any "immediate" and "easily" visible warning or message, this is also stated in the `readme_en.txt` file inside the XAMPP portable main folder.

> Step 1: Unpack the package into a directory of your choice. Please start the
> "setup_xampp.bat" and beginning the installation.
> Note: XAMPP makes no entries in the windows registry and no settings for the system variables.

I'd also say there is a not-so-clear note section right above this step:

> [NOTE: Unpack the package to your USB stick or a partition of your choice.
> There it must be on the highest level like E:\ or W:. It will
> build E:\xampp or W:\xampp or something like this. Please do not use the "setup_xampp.bat" for an USB stick installation!]

I've installed it in a random folder (not root) and after running the `setup_xampp.bat` script everything ran correctly.

Comment: Run setup_xampp.bat was the solution. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you are using xampp in USB Drive and having issue at different Windows PC/Laptop then Assign a relevant letter to USB according to installation PC/Laptop USB Letter.

Suppose You install xampp in USB at computer Alpha and Computer Alpha assign it letter F to USB and Now You are at other PC/Laptop Bravo and that PC/Laptop assign it to letter W by default then change that letter to F using Bravo system control panel.

[image: First Image]

[image: Second Image]

Answer (score 0):

**Problem: xampp Portable won’t start, failed or just doesn’t work!**

```
Error: Apache shutdown unexpectedly.
[Apache] This may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies,
[Apache] improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method.
[Apache] Press the Logs button to view error logs and check... ...
```

**Solution:**

**Option 2**

Step 1: Open Apache "httpd.conf" from xampp control panel. The file will open in notepad.

[image-xampp-config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMEYU.png)

Step 2: Scroll down or search for “ServerRoot”. If result => ServerRoot "/xampp/apache" follow next step. If not follow (Option 2)

[image-xammp-ServerRoot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fcCdr.png)

If 'httpd.conf' not like this image follow #Option 2

**Step 3:** For portable version of xampp don't any other folder name like 'xampp56'
Use only "**xampp**" And put this on **root directory**.
No Sub folder/directory

Step 4:  Open your USB drive and go to xampp folder, then start the xampp-control-panel with ‘run as administrator’ mode.

Done.

**Option 2**

Step 1: Open your ‘My Computer’ or ‘This PC’ to confirm your USB drive label on your current PC. E:, F:, G:…

Step 2: Open Apache "httpd.conf" from xampp control panel. The file will open in notepad. Now Scroll down or search for “ServerRoot”

[image-changing-file-httpd](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hx8Mj.png)

Step 3: There’s a file address path after the ServerRoot should change with your current USB drive address path if path not matches with this current PC.

[image-notepade-replace-function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Pw5K.png)

Step 4: Repeat the same process for Apache 'httpd-ssl.conf', 'httpd-xampp.conf',
'php.ini'(Please note that php using the backslash “\” instead of forward slash “/”)

[image-php-ini-config-update](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oyVYC.png)

and
{…your usb…}\xampp\apache\conf\extra\
File name: 'httpd-autoindex.conf', 'httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf'.

**Note:**  If xampp Portable Apache "httpd.conf" like Option 2 you have to Repeat this process Every time. I recommend you to download new version of '[xampp-portable-**win32**-... **.zip**](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/)'.

```
Otherwise total of 7 files need to be updated everytime you change
PC!! Apache ('httpd.conf', 'httpd-ssl.conf', 'httpd-xamp.conf')
'php.ini', 'my.ini', 'httpd-autoindex.conf',
'httpd-multilang-errordoc.conf'
```

Step 5: Open your USB drive and go to xampp folder, then start the xampp-control-panel with ‘run as administrator’ mode.

Done.