# XAMPP problems with apache

Tags: apache, xampp

just wanted to set up my XAMPP Control Panel.
Worked so far but there is something blocking my 80 Port. Its JavaW.exe. Whenever I taskkill it it gets opened again. When I switch the Apache Port to 8080 and start it there is a error telling me that the Apache got shut down unexpectedly. Reason for this could be a port which is already in use. But like I said. I had a look and 8080 is clear.
So.
First question. How to get javaw away from my port 80?
And second question why is it shutting down even if the port is not in use?

Greetings,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0):

Your goal should instead be to know what program requires java.exe. Read [here](https://superuser.com/q/212296/706430) more about it. Once knowing, changing its port should be straightforward.

The unexpected shutdown may be due to a blocked port, missing dependencies, improper privileges, a crash, or a shutdown by another method, as the error often points to. Try running as administrator and / or [changing the port to 81](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22023266/5675325), for instances.